# chamando uma função dentro de outra função em c

Tags: c, funções, struct, header

Eu preciso receber valores `float` para armazenar em uma `struct`, porem preciso que esses valores sejam validados por meio de uma função de validação.`

A função que le e valida esses valores esta funcionando corretamente, mas quando tento chamar ela dentro da função que vai armazenar dentro da `struct`acusa: "undefined reference to '`lerfloat`' ".

A função `lerfloat`:

```
float lerfloat()
{
    float f;
    char c;
    int ret;

    do
    {
        puts("Insira um numero: \n");
        ret=scanf("%f",&f);
        fflush(stdin);

        if(ret==1)
        {
            return f;
        }
        else{
            puts("Digite apenas numeros por favor.\n");}

    }while(ret!=1);
    return f;
}
```

A função para armazenar os valores:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "headLer.h"


struct armazenar
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

float func_lerVetor(float vet_pontos[][2], int n)
{
    struct armazenar p;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p.x= lerfloat();
        vet_pontos[i][0]=p.x;
        p.y= lerfloat();
        vet_pontos[i][1]=p.y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

headLer.h

```
#ifndef FUNCLERN_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCLERN_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int func_lerN();
float lerfloat();
float func_lerVetor();


#endif // FUNCLERN_H_INCLUDED
```

Eu não estou conseguindo ver onde estou errando, a função `lerfloat`esta devidamente definida em `headLer.h`.

ps.:a função chama ler vetor pq ela lê coordenadas de um vetor.
ps2.: eu ja tentei colocar o prototipo de `lerfloat`em `func_lerVetor`e o erro continuou.

Comment: A classe lerfloat foi compilada?

Comment: Você diz se ela funcionou corretamente? pq se for isso, sim, eu testei ela antes de implementar o func_lerVetor  e ela estava funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Esta utilizando o alguma IDE? ou fazendo tudo por linux, linha de comando e etc?

Comment: Ta tudo em projeto ou esta selecionando e dando build?

Comment: esta tudo em projeto.

Answer (score 1):

Os arquivos `.h` servem apenas para referencial de métodos, estruturas e valores, criar um método dentro de um arquivo de cabeçalho pode causar sérios problemas futuramente.

O correto seria tem outro arquivo `.c` com o método dentro.

**headLer.h:**

```
#pragma once // faz com que o arquivo não seja incluso mais de uma vez

float lerfloat();
```

**headLer.c:**

```
float lerfloat(){
    float f;
    char c;
    int ret;

    do
    {
        puts("Insira um numero: \n");
        ret=scanf("%f",&f);
        fflush(stdin);

        if(ret==1)
        {
            return f;
        }
        else{
            puts("Digite apenas numeros por favor.\n");}

    }while(ret!=1);
    return f;
}
```

**func_lerVetor.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "headLer.h"


struct armazenar
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

float func_lerVetor(float vet_pontos[][2], int n)
{
    struct armazenar p;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        p.x= lerfloat();
        vet_pontos[i][0]=p.x;
        p.y= lerfloat();
        vet_pontos[i][1]=p.y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Os arquivos `.c` devem ser todos compilados para terem a função dentro de si, assim podendo fazer a chamada.

Caso use o gcc:

```
gcc *.c -o program.exe
```

> Obs: Deve ter a função `main`, caso contrário seu código não será compilado.

Comment: O `lerfloat` está em um arquivo .c, aquele .h do começo foi so pra ver se não era isso que estava faltando. Vou colocar tambem o arquivo .h na pergunta.

Comment: @soAna como você está compilando seu código? está usando alguma IDE?

Comment: Acredito que sim, eu uso o code blocks.

Comment: tente jogar todos os métodos para um único arquivo `.c`, pode ser que o sua *IDE* não esteja compilando o projeto inteiro

Comment: não deu certo junta-los em um unico .c tambem

Comment: pode ser algum erro de lógica, faça upload do projeto e passe o link

Comment: aaah na verdade eu acabei de achar o erro. Tinha um arquivo teste na pasta do projeto (mas não incluso no projeto) que estava confundindo o compilador. Desculpa...

Comment: sem problemas..

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente pelo erro obtido, o compilador não está encontrando sua função, para resolver isso você precisa declarar o [protótipo da função](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prot%C3%B3tipo_de_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

> Segundo a wiki: "Se a função não for declarada previamente e o seu nome ocorre em alguma expressão seguida de um parêntese ("( "), ela é declarada implicitamente como uma função sem nenhum argumento que retorna um int."

No seu caso, seria apenas: `float lerFloat();`

Comment: Desculpa, eu esqueci de mencionar na pergunta, mas eu ja tentei isso tambem...

Comment: O arquivo "headLer.h" está na mesma pasta do arquivo .c ?

Comment: Onde você declarou o protótipo? O correto seria logo abaixo dos includes, fora de qualquer função.

Comment: sim, esta. na msm pasta, e declarei o prototipo logo abaixo dos includes e acima da struct, e tambem tentei logo abaixo da struct e não deu certo.